# Using Apollo client without hooks

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, apollo-client

I want to use Apollo Client for GraphQL queries/mutations/...

But I don't want to use hooks (e.g `useQuery(...)`).

I want to fetch the data regardless of the component lifecycle.

I want to store the data in my `Mobx` store.

So far, I found the coupling with `useQuery` and fetching the data and I want to bypass that.

Something like that:

```
async function fetchTodos() {
  store.setLoading(true);

  const todos = await service.runTodosQuery();
  store.setTodos(todos);

  store.setLoading(false);
}
```

I found [this](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/graphql/examples/4-simple-ways-to-call-a-graphql-api/) so far but I don't see how I can use apollo client without hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Before the introduction of hooks, Apollo Library had 2 ways to make the graphql request

1. Components - [Components](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/components/)
2. Hoc Pattern - [HOC pattern](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hoc/)

But the library has dropped support to both of them on march - 2020 . So its not recommended to use the above options.

If you still need to take a look at how the Component looks like. This might help you
[Apollo Query and Mutation Components](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/updated-for-apollo-v2-1-managing-local-state-with-apollo-d1882f2fbb7/)